# Is it acceptable to use Latin abbreviations in formal academic writings?

Tags: abbreviations, writing-style

Is it acceptable to use Latin abbreviations such as "etc" and "e.g." in formal academic writings? Personally I think, they are. However, somewhere I read I should avoid them. Is it correct?

In general, are not Latin abbreviations more formal than "OK" or "&"?

Comment: FWIW, the ampersand is just a stylized form of the Latin word 'et'

Comment: It is acceptable to use them *correctly*.

Comment: @Josh61 this question is more general than that one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they're allowed, but should be used sparingly. This link explains it better than me: http://www.arcticllama.com/blog/writing-tips/grammar/etc-et-al-ap-style-writing/

Comment: I'd be careful taking advice from a website that thinks *et cetera* is one word.